# How to reset a NetLogo model with an extension?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working on a NetLogo model that has a great deal of information stored in lookup tables and embedded in patches that affect agent behavior.  As a result, I'm creating a model "reset" from an extension that clears the turtles, and resets the timer and ticks.

I would also like to have the extension reset specific globals that track model results, but not reset all of the globals that are constants (look up tables of precomputed information).  I would also like to reset all the interface plots.

Any thoughts on how to go about this?

I apologize for no code to show, as is the case I can't show what is not working because I'm not even sure what to try!

Comment: It's a little unclear what the global values get reset to. Something stored for each run, or some value that is always the same?

Comment: Just create a procedure `reset-results-globals` and call it during setup.  (Although if these globals are really just holding results, and if the results are set as the model runs, it is not entirely clear why you need to reset them at all.)

Comment: There are some global a that I need to retain and others that can be reset to 0 or false, the defaults NetLogo uses. I can reset from NetLogo itself, but am trying to manage the activity through an extension. It may be unnecessary, but I'm trying to push more code into extensions for better performance.

Comment: Pusing the initialization of these globals (and the plots) into an extension will buy you almost nothing.  Btw, to avoid resetting the others, just don't call `clear-all` or `reset-globals`.  Finally, I find the idea of "retaining" some globals across runs pretty dubious, even though you promise they will always remain constant.  Promises, promises ...

Comment: @Alan, suppose you want to add a "reset to the previous seed" button, so that you can examine a run more closely?

Comment: Aaron F., I think Seth Tisue's answer provides the background information that you need.  The key point is that you probably want to avoid calling `clear-all-globals`, but then provide a procedure that sets globals to the values you want. Other than that, what kind of answer could be given other than "write code that sets some variables and not others"?  If you have a lot of globals, this will require care to make sure none are missed, and to make sure that you change the "clear/reset" procedure when you add a global variable. At present NetLogo has no way to set default initialization values.

Comment: Seth's  answer was helpful and I have a command in the extension called `resetWorld` (on the NetLogo side appears as `extension-name:reset-world`) that clears the turtles, resets all globals that are not on the interface or in a list of constants that do not change from run-to-run.  The challenge was not the conceptual part but the implementation.  I knew how to get the names of globals as Strings, but not how to change them.  I was less successful in resetting plots, because I can't find a path back from the extension command into the interface to find the Plot objects or PlotManagers.

Answer (score 1):

NetLogo engine internals aren't really documented except in a general way at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Engine-architecture, so if your extension wants to manipulate engine stuff directly, you'll usually have to consult the NetLogo source code to learn specifics of how it's done.

You want something like `clear-globals`, so check out https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/5.x/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/etc/_clearglobals.scala and https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/37cc1a0aa371c11e89f5b39b5143ed5d951e6081/src/main/org/nlogo/agent/World.java#L849-L866.

You want something like `clear-all-plots`, so check out https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/37cc1a0aa371c11e89f5b39b5143ed5d951e6081/src/main/org/nlogo/prim/plot/primitives.scala#L45-L50 and https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/37cc1a0aa371c11e89f5b39b5143ed5d951e6081/src/main/org/nlogo/plot/PlotManager.scala#L54-L57.

And so on.

EDIT:

For access to the PlotManager, note that plot/primitives.scala has:

```
workspace.plotManager.asInstanceOf[PlotManager]
```

in Java code on an extension, from the workspace `plotManager()` gets you the PlotManager, except the return type of that method is Object (yes, I know, it's grungy and horrible), so you need to insert a typecast to `org.nlogo.plot.PlotManager` and you're good to go. PlotManager has methods for getting to particular plots.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get control over the globals.  I have been less successful finding a way to access Plots or PlotManagers from an extension.  How do I access the objects I'm looking for?  Is there something from the ClassManager or Command that would give me access to what I'm looking for?  Even for not resetting plots, just being able to update them from a extension would be helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer to include additional information about getting a hold of PlotManager.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try it tonight.

Comment: I was unable to access the `ExtensionManager` and will open a new question on this.  Thanks.

Comment: Heh, it looks from Bryan's answer to that question that you actually get to ExtensionManager through workspace. But workspace was what you actually wanted here. So you'll want to use the part of Bryan's answer that gets you a workspace, and skip the part that gets you to ExtensionManager, which you don't need. Sorry, I'm a little rusty on this stuff. (Answer edited slightly.)